# How to filter a dictionary value (within another dictionary)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I will try to explain this as best as i can, so apologies in advanced for the long post.

Firstly, I have an API here (http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/_all_docs) and within this dictionary there are 5000 other dictionaries that I can access through their ID (http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/30e901a7b7d8e98328dcd77c369b6ad7)

So far I've created a programme that sorts through these dictionaries and only prints out (to csv) the dictionaries related to a user input sector (e.g. healthcare)

However, I wanted to be able to implement a filter search, so that the programme will only print statements that are above or below a user input value e.g. Only retrieve data from (user input) closing stock and only companies below (<=) a value of closing stock - 40,000.

My problem is that, I'm not necessarily sure *how* to.

I understand how to get the user input, and how to access the dictionary within dictionary but i have no idea how to filter above or below a user input value.

Here is a copy of my code, any pointers would be appreciated!

```
import urllib #Imports the url - library module (older the urllib2 but has some useful decodes if needed)
import urllib2 #Imports the Url- Library module (Most recently updated + used)
import csv #Imports the commands that allows for csv writing/reading
import json #Imports the ability to read/use Json data
import time #Imports the time module - allows the developer to examine benchmarks (How long did it take to fetch data)
import os


income_csv = csv.writer(open("Income Statement_ext.csv", "wb")) #This creates a CSV file and writes functions to it
financial_csv = csv.writer(open("Statement of financial position_ext.csv", "wb"))

#The two csv 'writers' create the headers for the information within the CSV file before the information from the api is added to it
financial_csv.writerow([
    ('Company name'),
    ('Non Current Assets'),
    ('Current Assets'),
    ('Equity'),
    ('Non-Current Assets'),
    ('Current Liabilities')])

income_csv.writerow([
    ('Company name'),
    ('Sales'),
    ('Opening Stock'),
    ('Purchases'),
    ('Closing Stock'),
    ('Expenses'),
    ('Interest payable'),
    ('Interest receivable')])

income_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/_all_docs"
income_request = urllib2.urlopen(income_url).read()
income_response = json.loads(income_request)
#defines the income url

financial_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/financial_positions/_all_docs"
financial_request = urllib2.urlopen(financial_url).read()
financial_response = json.loads(financial_request)
#defines the financial postion url
count = 0
#sets the count for documents printed to 0
def income_statement_fn():
    global count #allows for the count to be kept globally
    print ("(Type help if you would like to see the available choices)")
    income_user_input = raw_input("Which sector would you like to iterate through in Income Statement?: ").lower()# Asks the user which sector within the chosen statement he/she would like to examine
    if income_user_input == "help":
        print ("Available sectors are: ")
        print ("Technology")
        print ("Healthcare")
        print ("Industrial goods")
        print ("Financial")
        print ("Utilities")
        print ("Basic materials")
        print ("Services") 
        income_statement_fn()

    elif income_user_input == "technology" or income_user_input == "healthcare" or income_user_input == "industrial goods" or income_user_input == "financial" or income_user_input == "utilities" or income_user_input == "basic materials" or income_user_input == "services":
        print 'Starting...' # I use this print to set a milestone (if it prints this, everything before it has worked without error)
        start = time.clock()
        start
        for item in income_response['rows']:
            is_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/" + item['id'] #This combines the api with the array's ID's allowing us to access every document automatically
            is_request = urllib2.urlopen(is_url).read() #Opens is_url and reads the data
            is_response = json.loads(is_request) #loads the data in json format
            if is_response.get ('sector') == income_user_input: #matches the sector the user inputed - allows us to access that dictionary
                income_csv.writerow([
                 is_response['company']['name'],
                 is_response['company']['sales'],
                 is_response['company']['opening_stock'],
                 is_response['company']['purchases'],
                 is_response['company']['closing_stock'],
                 is_response['company']['expenses'],
                 is_response['company']['interest_payable'],
                 is_response['company']['interest_receivable']]) # The lines of code above write the chosen fields to the csv file
            count +=1
            print ("filtering statements") + ("( "+" %s "+" )") % count
        start
        print start
        restart_fn()
    else:
        print ("Invalid input!")
        income_statement_fn()





def financial_statement_fn(): # Within this function is the code required to fetch information related to the financial position statement
    global count # Allows for the count to be kept globally (outside the function)
    print ("(Type help if you would like to see the available choices)")
    financial_user_input = raw_input("Which sector would you like to iterate through in financial statements?: ").lower()
    if financial_user_input == "help":
        print ("Available sectors are: ")
        print ("Technology")
        print ("Healthcare")
        print ("Industrial goods")
        print ("Financial")
        print ("Utilities")
        print ("Basic materials")
        print ("Services")
        financial_statement_fn()

    elif financial_user_input == "technology" or financial_user_input == "healthcare" or financial_user_input == "industrial goods" or financial_user_input == "financial" or financial_user_input == "utilities" or financial_user_input == "basic materials" or financial_user_input == "services":
        print 'Starting'
        for item in financial_response['rows']:
            fs_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/financial_positions/" + item['id']#This combines the api with the array's ID's allowing us to access every document automatically
            fs_request = urllib2.urlopen(fs_url).read()
            fs_response = json.loads(fs_request)
            if fs_response.get ('sector') == financial_user_input:
                financial_csv.writerow([
                    fs_response['company']['name'],
                    fs_response['company']['non_current_assets'],
                    fs_response['company']['current_assets'],
                    fs_response['company']['equity'],
                    fs_response['company']['non_current_liabilities'],
                    fs_response['company']['current_liabilities']])
                count +=1
                print ("printing statements") + ("( "+" %s "+" )") % count
        print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print ("finished fetching data")
        print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
        restart_fn()

    else:
        print ("Invalid Input!")
        financial_statement_fn()


def launch_fn():
    print ("Please type 'help' if you would like to examine all available options")
    launch_user_input = raw_input("Welcome, Which statement would you like to examine?: ").lower()
    if launch_user_input == "income" or launch_user_input == "income statement":
        income_statement_fn()
    elif launch_user_input == "financial" or launch_user_input == "financial statement":
        financial_statement_fn()
    elif launch_user_input == "help" :
        print ("You can use the following commands on this menu: ")
        print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print ("Income or Income statement")
        print ("Will allow you to retrieve data relating to financial Income statements")
        print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print ("Financial or Financial statement")
        print ("Will allow you to retrieve data relating to the statement of financial position")
        print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
        launch_fn()
    else:
        print ("If you would like to look at the available options please type help")
        launch_fn()

def restart_fn():
    restart_prompt = raw_input("Would you like to examine another statement?: ").lower()
    if restart_prompt == 'y' or restart_prompt == 'yes':
        launch_fn()
        count = 0
    elif restart_prompt == 'n' or restart_prompt == 'no':
        raise SystemExit("Shutting down....")

def restart_api_down_fn():
    print ("Type 'y' or 'yes' to continue, 'n' or 'no' to exit or 'r' or 'reconnect' to test servers again")
    restart_prompt_api = raw_input("Would you like to continue anyway?: ").lower()
    if restart_prompt_api == 'r' or restart_prompt_api == 'reconnect' or restart_prompt_api == 'test':
        api_status_fn()
        count = 0
    elif restart_prompt_api == 'n' or restart_prompt_api == 'no':
        raise SystemExit("Shutting down....")
    elif restart_prompt_api == 'y' or restart_prompt_api == 'yes':
        print (" Continuing... Programme performance may be severely affected")
        launch_fn()
    else:
        print ("Invalid input...")
        restart_api_down_fn()

def api_status_fn():
    hostname_income = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements" 
    response_income = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname_income)
    hostname_financial = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/financial_positions"
    response_financial = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname_financial)
    global count
    count = 0

    if response_income == 0:
        print hostname_income, 'is up!'
        count +=1
    else:
        print hostname_income, 'is experiencing connection issues!'        

    if response_financial == 0:
        print hostname_financial, 'is up!'
        count +=1

    else:
        print hostname_financial, 'is experiencing connection issues!'

    if count == 2:
        launch_fn()

    elif count == 0:
        restart_api_down_fn() # Code only for UNIX SYSTEMS?

#def api_status_fn():
 #   hostname = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements"
  #  ping = urllib.urlopen(hostname).getcode()
   # if ping == "200":
     #   print 'oh no!'
# add filtering & sorting







api_status_fn()
```

Please let me know if you need any additional explanations,

Cheers!

Comment: I haven't read your code, but would something like `filtered_d = {id: subdict for id, subdict in d.iteritems() if d["Closing Stock"] <= 40000}` work?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your code is quite confused and you may have more luck with it if you try to break it down a little. I will try to make some suggestions towards the end of this answer.

Fundamentally you need to filter the specific results that you get. Looking at your code I can see the following:

```
elif financial_user_input == "technology" or financial_user_input == "healthcare" or financial_user_input == "industrial goods" or financial_user_input == "financial" or financial_user_input == "utilities" or financial_user_input == "basic materials" or financial_user_input == "services":
    print 'Starting'
    for item in financial_response['rows']:
        fs_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/financial_positions/" + item['id']#This combines the api with the array's ID's allowing us to access every document automatically
        fs_request = urllib2.urlopen(fs_url).read()
        fs_response = json.loads(fs_request)
        if fs_response.get ('sector') == financial_user_input:
```

This code mixes the following responsibilities up:

- Validating user input
- Requesting records
- Filtering records

If you split out these responsibilities into separate methods then you will find that your code is easier to reason about. Also, as I will shortly show, splitting things up in this way allows you to recombine the different parts to customise the way in which the records are filtered etc.

If it gets split up a little:

```
def _get_single_record(id):
    """ Request an individual financial position.
        This does not filter """
    ... read and return the json decoded data ...

def _record_matches_sector(record, sector):
    """ Determine if the record provided matches the sector """
    return record['sector'] == sector

def _record_meets_closing_stock_limit(record, limit):
    """ Determine if the record provided has a
        closing stock of at least limit """
    return record['closing stock'] >= limit

def _get_all_filtered_records(ids, sector, limit):
    """ Return all financial position records that
        match the sector and closing stock limit """
    record_generator = (_get_single_record(id) for id in ids)
    return (
        record for record in record_generator
        if _record_matches_sector(record, sector)
        and _record_meets_closing_stock_limit(record, limit)
    )
```

This obviously just returns a generator which returns the records that match your sector and limit. You can add more tests and so on, but updating the code to test for each of these is still quite manual. What you need is a way to apply some selectable tests to the record_generator and return the results that match.

This is quite trivial in python because python treats functions as first class objects (meaning you can assign them to variables) and you can create custom functions quickly using lambdas. This means you can restate the `_get_all_filtered_records` as:

```
def _make_limit_test(limit):
    """ This returns a function which accepts records that meet the limit """
    return lambda record: record['closing stock'] >= limit

def _make_sector_test(sector):
    """ This returns a function which accepts records that match the sector """
    return lambda record: record['sector'] == sector

def _filter_records_by_tests(ids, tests):
     """ Returns all the records that pass all the tests """
     record_generator = (_get_single_financial_position_record(id) for id in ids)
     for record in record_generator:
         if all(test(record) for test in tests):
             yield record
```

You can then build the list of tests to pass by asking the user. This would be a sufficient demo just to verify that this approach works:

```
def demo_filtering_by_healthcare_and_40k(ids):
    tests = [_make_sector_test("healthcare"), _make_limit_test(40000)]
    return _filter_records_by_tests(ids, tests)
```

As you can see my method names are quite long and the methods are quite short. This is really a matter of personal style, but I find that doing it that way makes it obvious what a method does and allows you to quickly comprehend the code to verify that it matches the name.

So to wrap this up, you are requesting records from the remote api. You can filter these by using list comprehensions. List comprehensions are extremely powerful and allow you to take source data and transform it and filter it. It would help you a lot to read about them.

Comment: I have to admit, this list comprehension looks incredibly stream-lined and your explanation is fantastic. Unfortunately i haven't been able to get it to work yet, but i think i just need to practice my python as i'm pretty sure i'm not doing it right.. I will let you know how it works out when i re-write my code in this format - Cheers!

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues with this. Something not immediately obvious is whether the list comprehension returns a list or a generator. If the comprehension is surrounded by () it returns a generator, while [] returns a list. If you try to index something and it fails then see if the object is actually a generator. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators